# Do pounds convert to kilograms or newtons?

Tags: units, si-units

I'm currently writing an essay titled "What Will Replace the Space Shuttle?"

I'm having no problem finding sources of information, however most of my sources are North American in origin. (The space shuttle was American after all). This means data relating to weights and forces, for example, are given in pounds.

As a British physics student I have been taught to use SI units. Should I convert from pounds to kilograms, or pounds to newtons? Given the original numbers are likely to have been rounded, would I add extra uncertainty by converting?

Comment: It might be worth asking whoever is checking your essay (I assume it is something that will be marked/read by someone) what they want? Personally I would stick to the source units to avoid any unnecessary errors.

Comment: I hear that American students who still use British units for day-to-day *are also taught* to use SI units for physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The American system is confusing because "pound" is the word for two *different* units, one of mass and one of force. The latter is sometimes written "pound-force" (lbf.) when the author cares to make the distinction, but you can't generally count on this. So you'll have to infer which is which from context. If a quantity is a force (including a weight), the proper SI unit is the newton. If it's a mass, the unit is the kilogram. (Or multiples thereof, e.g. meganewtons or micrograms or whatever.)

The definitions of the two pounds are such that an object with a mass of one pound will have a weight of one pound-force under standard gravity ($g = 9.80665\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$).

As far as rounding, there is nothing special here that doesn't apply to any other unit conversion. You can probably use the standard significant figure rules.

Comment: Your answer would be more complete if you included the conversion factor between the kilogram and the pound.

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio Yes, it would, and it would be even more complete if I included a whole bunch of other things. But I have to stop somewhere. It's trivial to look up that conversion factor, and that's not what the question is asking for, so I elected to leave it out.

Comment: What happened to slug as the mass unit in the British system of units?

Comment: @LewisMiller We don't use it in the US, though if you want to know any more that might make a good question for [hsm.SE].

Comment: We did use in the US when I was an undergrad (1960s).

Comment: @LewisMiller there is no such thing as "the British system of units". The only unit system that can be legally used for any commercial purpose in the UK is SI - except that beer is sold in pints (which in any case are a different size from US pints) and road distances and speed limits use miles.